# What fault in my json file?

Tags: php, json

I have a json file, called: openingstijden.json

```
{
    "openingstijden": {
        "normaal": {
            ["10.00", "18.00"],
            ["8.00", "16.00"],
            ["8.00", "18.00"],
            ["8.00", "18.00"],
            ["8.00", "18.00"],
            ["8.00", "18.00"],
            ["8.00", "18.00"]
        },
        "speciaal": {
            "2013-11-20": ["12.00", "20.00"]
        }
    }
}
```

But when I try to make a vardump on this array

```
// path naar config file
define('CONFIG_FILE', __DIR__.'/openingstijden.json');

$businessHours = json_decode(file_get_contents(CONFIG_FILE), true);

var_dump($businessHours);
```

I get this result: NULL
and also when i try to foreach the array:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Do you guys know what is wrong with my json file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your JSON is invalid.

Comment: You can't put an array in an object like that.  You're `normaal` should be an array, not an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Your JSON string is invalid.** Every entry in valid JSON must have a key for the value. The seven lines starting with `["10.00", "18.00"],` do not have a key as `"2013-11-20": ["12.00", "20.00"]` does.

To make it valid...

```
{
    "openingstijden": {
        "normaal": {
            "0": ["10.00", "18.00"],
            "1": ["8.00", "16.00"],
            "2": ["8.00", "18.00"],
            "3": ["8.00", "18.00"],
            "4": ["8.00", "18.00"],
            "5": ["8.00", "18.00"],
            "6": ["8.00", "18.00"]
        },
        "speciaal": {
            "2013-11-20": ["12.00", "20.00"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just curious, wouldn't an unsorted array work as well? Is there any reason why you should make them key-vals?

Comment: @sheeptest JSON requires a key for every entry. You don't have to go in order, i.e. `0`, `1`, `2`, etc., but it's logical for this case.

Comment: :X thank you. When I pasted my example into [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com) it came back as valid.

Comment: @sheeptest Yours doesn't validate for me. It returns "Parse error on line 3."

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a key for your "normaal" values, you can replace the {} with [].
In this case you'd have an array accessible by the key "normaal" with arrays in it.